# Maven error stating that PKIX path building failed: unable to find the valid certificate

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, pkix

While i am building the code in my local, I am getting this error.

I have tried downloading the certificate from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, and through cmd , i have given the command to trust the certificate but this has not solved the problem.

Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.junit:junit-bom:pom:5.6.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Please help me how I can fix this issue

I have tried downloading the certificate from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, and through cmd , i have given the command to trust the certificate but this has not solved the problem.

Comment: The certificate of maven central should be accepted without any changes

Comment: Which Java version do you use? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise, Java version used is "11.0.13"  and Maven version is Apache Maven 3.5.2

Comment: It might be useful to know where you are executing this from.  Are you behind a corporate firewall?  It's possible your enterprise requires a specific intermediate root certificate installed in your JDK's cacerts truststore.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Maven 3.9 they changed the default Transport implementation to **native**.

Try with this option to disable SSL verifications:

```
mvn compile -Daether.connector.https.securityMode=insecure
```

Background:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-resolver-transport.html